# Dagger 2.12 Proguard rules

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-proguard, dagger

I'm using Dagger 2.12 with new  [Android injector](https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe). When I try to make singed apk with proguard enabled, I get the following error

[image]

Can anyone show the proper proguard rules for Dagger 2.12?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**
```

Comment: Thanks!! Working fine